# Appropriate model for tv audience data analysis

Tags: repeated-measures, modeling, model-selection, multilevel-analysis, model

I want to perform analysis on tv audience data of one specific tv shows. I have the average rating (amount of viewers in 1000s) for each minute. Since it is a "standardized" tv show, there are reoccurring elements in each show (e.g. music performance, long interview, etc.). More than 20 episodes have been broadcasted, with length of 45 minutes.

My primary focus is to compare ratings of the reoccurring elements of the show and determine which element leads to loss of the audience. The model should include the audience ratings for the other stations during my focus tv show as independent variables and other variables.

With my (limited) knowledge I would use multilevel linear modeling approach, trying to use episodes and events as levels. I would appreciate any advice on choosing the model or modeling approach and how to best address the issues I mentioned:

1. The data are (repeated measures) time series.
2. Minutes within the show are not independent measurements.

edit: To be clear, my dependant variable is rating of the show measured in each minute. My independent variables are ratings for each minutes for other tv stations (during the duration of the program). Plus I might add other variables for clustered minutes, such as if the guest was celebrity or not.

Comment: I think it may help people trying to understand your question if you explicitly state which variables you have, their meaning and the number of samples. I know it can probably be extracted from your text, but it would make it easier to understand.